# Why is Javascript's "in" operator consistently slower than strict member comparison to undefined?

Tags: javascript

See http://jsperf.com/in-vs-member-object-access

Essentially, why is checking `if ('bar' in foo) {}` significantly slower than `if (foo.bar !== undefined) {}`?

Comment: [Similar benchmark with similar results](http://jsperf.com/in-versus-bracket-versus-dot)

Comment: My results were the same. However there are other good candidates to check existence instead of "in", see http://jsperf.com/dictionary-contains-key

Answer (score 5):

`foo.bar !== undefined` checks just those 2 values to see if they match.

While `'bar' in foo` will have to use some mechanism to loop through the properties of `foo` to see if `bar` is in it.

Here is an interesting Read from  Ecma-script

> ## The in operator
>
> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>   1. Evaluate RelationalExpression.
>   2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
>   3. Evaluate ShiftExpression.
>   4. Call GetValue(Result(3)).
>   5. If Result(4) is not an object, throw a TypeError exception.
>   6. Call ToString(Result(2)).
>   7. Call the [[HasProperty]] method of Result(4) with parameter Result(6).
>   8. Return Result(7).
>
> ## The Strict Does-not-equal Operator ( !== )
>
> The production EqualityExpression : EqualityExpression !== RelationalExpression is evaluated as follows:
>   1. Evaluate EqualityExpression.
>   2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
>   3. Evaluate RelationalExpression.
>   4. Call GetValue(Result(3)).
>   5. Perform the comparison Result(4) === Result(2). (See below.)
>   6. If Result(5) is true, return false. Otherwise, return true.

Comment: Thanks for posting this information directly inline to your answer. I've already accepted an answer, but I really appreciate taking your time to put this in here. I'm sure others will find it invaluable.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; determining whether there's a `bar` property in `foo` is the first step in both operations. There's no reason `'bar' in foo` couldn't be just as `foo.bar !== undefined`. The reason `in` is slower is that it hasn't been optimized much.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff I'm not convinced that `'bar' in foo` is identical to `foo.bar !== undefined`, either semantically or in terms of implementation. Consider the following code `x = {}; x.a = undefined;`. After executing these two statements, what would you expect the result of `('a' in x) == (x.a !== undefined)` to be? I would argue that the current behavior, `false` is what should happen, whereas you seem to be arguing that the result should be `true`.

Comment: They're not identical. But there is no reason they can't be equally fast.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. It makes no sense for `"bar" in foo` to be slower than `foo.bar`.

The only reason `in` isn't just as fast is that it hasn't received as much attention from JIT engineers as the much more common `foo.bar` syntax.

Especially in the case in your jsperf test, where the property *does* exist as a direct property on `foo` itself (not a prototype), it stands to reason that `'bar' in foo` shouldn't be any slower than `foo.bar !== undefined`. If anything, it should be faster. The main difference between the two is that `in` can be answered without even checking the value of the property!

In the `foo.bar` case, I expect both the V8 engine and the SpiderMonkey engine will detect that the code isn't doing anything useful (that is, it has no observable effects) and optimize it away entirely. The benchmark isn't measuring any actual work.

Apparently engines are not yet smart enough to optimize away `"bar" in foo`, but it's only a matter of time. And priorities.