# Why is the 'in' operator so slow in JS?

Tags: javascript, performance

Here is the JSPerf [link](http://jsperf.com/javascript-in-operator-performance)

How could merely checking if a property exists be slower than retrieving it?

Also why is localStorage actually faster? Is it because it is accessing disk?

Comment: 1% faster on Google Chrome... Doesn't seem to be a significant margin. What numbers are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure? Mine goes from 10000 to 60000 ops/s.

Maybe I'm looking at it completely wrong.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, misread the results.

Comment: Seems this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866442/why-is-javascripts-in-operator-consistently-slower-than-strict-member-compari

Comment: @Dave: The answer to that other question doesn't make sense. They're both doing the same thing... looking up a property.

Comment: @amnotiam I'd say take that up with Asad!

Comment: @amnotiam The spec I wrote that answer from was this [1999 version](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf). My understanding was that JS implements objects similarly to hashtables meaning that retrieving a key and its corresponding value is O(1) (hash the key, now you know where the key and value are), whereas looking through all hashes to check if one of them has a matching key is O(n). I still suspect my guess is correct, even though the new spec has changed to reduce both HasProperty and Get to GetProperty.